# File upload using HTML file type

Tags: asp.net, html, file-upload

I want to upload a file on my aspx page.

I am using

```
<form id="frmId" method="post" enctype="Multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="file1"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnsubmit"/>
</form>
```

and in code behind I am trying to get this file. Its not letting me to get the file until I use server side input file control. I don't want to use **runat="server"** attribute with my file control.

Do anyone know how to do this.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `runat="server"` ?

Comment: It will make my control a server control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access control on server side code with out `runat="server"` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Request.Files collection?